# Receiving Video Stream with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, video, video-streaming

I'm facing an issue with python 2.7. My code in python 3 was fine and able to capture a live video stream from Pi camera. However, I had to convert my code to python 2.7 and unfortunately I failed to receive a video stream with this line

```
import cv2
faceDetect=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml');
id=0
font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cam = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.1.4/html/cam_pic_new.php?time=1508161104695&pDelay=40000',cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
rec=cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer();
rec.load('trainer/training.yml')
while cam.isOpened():
    ret, img= cam.read();
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5);
    if(cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('x')):
        break;
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The error says: 'module' object has no attribute 'CAP_FFMPEG'

Comment: Check the value of `cv2.__version__` in both python2 and python3.

Comment: do you mean like this: cam = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.1.4/html/cam_pic_new.php?time=1508161104695&pDelay=40000',cv2.__version__)... If I try it it says error type video capture takes 1 argument only

Comment: I mean `print(cv2.__version__)`, in both python2 and python3.

Comment: Python 3: the version is 3.1.0, Python 2: the version is 2.4.11

Comment: You're using two different versions of OpenCV. One version is not built with FFMPEG support.

Comment: You are correct. Thanks for your help. I updated the openCV from 2 to 3.